# How to read merged cells in python using openpyxl?

Tags: python, openpyxl

I'm trying to read data from the excel file that has merged_cells_range... but the output is not my goal. Pls help me out

```
import openpyxl
wb = openpyxl.load_workbook('book1.xlsx')
sheet = wb.get_sheet_by_name('info')
all_data=[]
print(sheet.merged_cells.ranges)
for row_index in range(1,sheet.max_row+1):
    row=[]
    for col_index in range(1,sheet.max_column+1):
        vals = sheet.cell(row_index,col_index).value
        if vals =='':
            for crange in sheet.merged_cells.ranges:
                rlo,rhi,clo,chi = crange
                if rlo<=row_index and row_index<rhi and clo<=col_index and col_index<chi:
                    vals = sheet.cell(rlo,clo).value
                    print(vals)
                    break
        row.append(vals)
    all_data.append(row)
print(all_data)
for row in all_data:
    sheet.append(row)
wb.save('bbbb.xlsx')
```

I desired to get output:
[['06B', 'Daewoo BC 212', 80, 1373], ['06C', 'Daewoo BC 212', 80, 1020], ['06D', 'Transinco B60KL', 60, 1061], ['06D', 'Transinco B60KL', 60, 19], ['06E', 'Daewoo BC 212', 80, 1020], ['06E', 'Daewoo BC 212', 60, 1061], ['06E', 'Daewoo BC 212', 60, 19]] but results is:

[['06B', 'Daewoo BC 212', 80, 1373], ['06C', 'Daewoo BC 212', 80, 1020], ['06D', 'Transinco B60KL', 60, 1061], [None, None, 60, 19], ['06E', 'Daewoo BC 212', 80, 1020], [None, None, 60, 1061], [None, None, 60, 19]]

[my input](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jOl8z.png)
[output desired](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oXmv9.png)

Comment: You might find it easier to unmerge the relevant ranges and duplicate the columns accordingly.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I amend my code and it's work.

```
import openpyxl
from openpyxl.utils import range_boundaries
wb = openpyxl.load_workbook('book1.xlsx')
sheet = wb.get_sheet_by_name('info')
all_data=[]
for row_index in range(1,sheet.max_row+1):
    row=[]
    for col_index in range(1,sheet.max_column+1):
        vals = sheet.cell(row_index,col_index).value
        if vals == None:
            for crange in sheet.merged_cells:
                clo,rlo,chi,rhi = crange.bounds
                top_value = sheet.cell(rlo,clo).value
                if rlo<=row_index and row_index<=rhi and clo<=col_index and col_index<=chi:
                vals = top_value
                    print(vals)
                    break
    row.append(vals)
all_data.append(row)
print(all_data)
for row in all_data:
    sheet.append(row)
wb.save('bbbb.xlsx')
```

Comment: row_index<=rhi; col_index<=chi,

Answer (score 3):

I think this is more clear than the existed answer.

```
from openpyxl.cell import MergedCell

def parser_merged_cell(sheet: openpyxl.Workbook, row, col):
    cell = sheet.cell(row=row, column=col)
    if isinstance(cell, MergedCell):
        for merged_range in sheet.merged_cells.ranges:
            if cell.coordinate in merged_range:
                # return the left top cell
                cell = sheet.cell(row=merged_range.min_row, column=merged_range.min_col)
                break
    return cell.value
```

Answer (score 0):

There You go:

=^..^=

```
import openpyxl
from openpyxl import Workbook

# load data
raw_data = openpyxl.load_workbook('data.xlsx')
select_sheet = raw_data['Sheet1']


# collect data from rows
valid_row = []
data = []
for row in select_sheet.iter_rows(max_row=select_sheet.max_row, max_col=select_sheet.max_column):
    # get cell values
    row_data = [cell.value for cell in row]

    # handle merged cells
    new_row_data = [0]*select_sheet.max_column
    if None in row_data:
        new_row_data[0] = valid_row[0]
        new_row_data[1] = valid_row[1]
        new_row_data[2] = row_data[2]
        new_row_data[3] = row_data[3]
        data.append(new_row_data)
    else:
        data.append(row_data)
    # storage valid row
    if None not in row_data:
        valid_row = row_data


# save data
book = Workbook()
new_sheet = book.active

for row in data:
    new_sheet.append(row)

book.save('new_data.xlsx')
```

Input:

```
     0    1    2    3
0    B   212   80  1.2
1    C   212   80  1.3
2    D   B60   60  1.4
3  None  None  60  1.5
4    E   212   80  1.6
5  None  None  60  1.7
6  None  None  60  1.8
```

Output:

```
   0    1   2    3
0  B  212  80  1.2
1  C  212  80  1.3
2  D  B60  60  1.4
3  D  B60  60  1.5
4  E  212  80  1.6
5  E  212  60  1.7
6  E  212  60  1.8
```

Comment: Thanks, but i am trying to use python + openpyxl...to learn about more

Comment: @TuanNguyen try to analyse my code and find the differences. You make too many loops. And I don't see where you handle None cells

Comment: `values_only=True` means you don't have to have a list comprehension just to get the values.