# Reading merged cells from Excel File & store them within dataframe (Using Python)

Tags: python, excel, merge, cell, openpyxl

I have a table in an excel that contains many merged cells.

[Given Excel Table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Sqdwz.png)
When I open it with python, I want to be able to turn it into a dataframe while maintaining data integrity. It should look like this:

[Final Table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4FLTU.png)

I've searched through and referred to a few of the different solutions here:

[How to read merged cells in python using openpyxl?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56880675/how-to-read-merged-cells-in-python-using-openpyxl)

[How to read merged Excel cells with NaN into Pandas DataFrame](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47834025/how-to-read-merged-excel-cells-with-nan-into-pandas-dataframe?rq=1)

But none have worked.

Understand that fillna will fill up even cells that were originally not merged. I also read a little about merged_cell but am still unable to make it work.

```py
import openpyxl
from openpyxl.utils import range_boundaries
from openpyxl import Workbook
from openpyxl import load_workbook

# wb = Workbook()
wb = openpyxl.load_workbook('file')
sheet = wb.active

mcells = sheet.merged_cells.ranges
# mcells gives a list of merged cells

# I want to go through the list of merged cells and use sheet.unmerge_cells() to unmerge them and fill the cells accordingly. 
# This way I can ensure cells that are not merged will remain blank.

for k,v in enumerate(mcells):
  print(v)

# How do I continue from here?
```

Is there a way to do convert the merged cells accurately?

Comment: You should include whatever relevant code you've written.

Comment: Just updated with the code I have written so far.

Comment: See https://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/en/stable/usage.html#merge-unmerge-cells